# Renumbering a 1D mesh in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

First of all, I couldn't find the answer in other questions.

I have a numpy array of integer, this is called ELEM, the array has three columns that indicate, element number, node 1 and node 2. This is one dimensional mesh. What I need to do is to renumber the nodes, I have the old and new node numbering tables, so the algorithm should replace every value in the ELEM array according to this tables.

The code should look like this

```
old_num = np.array([2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 4, 7])
new_num = np.arange(1,10)
ELEM = np.array([ [1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 6], [3, 1, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

From now, for every element in the second and third column of the ELEM array I should replace every integer from the corresponding integer specified according to the new_num table.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?  This seems straightforward but it's hard to tell from just text.

Comment: Can you post the result of replace for your example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a lot of these, it makes sense to encode the renumbering in a dictionary for fast lookup.

```
lookup_table = dict( zip( old_num, new_num ) ) # create your translation dict
vect_lookup = np.vectorize( lookup_table.get ) # create a function to do the translation
ELEM[:, 1:] = vect_lookup( ELEM[:, 1:] ) # Reassign the elements you want to change
```

np.vectorize is just there to make things nicer syntactically. All it does is allow us to map over the values of the array with our lookup_table.get function

Comment: thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm new into Python and I've never used dictionaries. :)

Comment: Oh! In that case I imagine T-1000's answer is clearer. Dictionaries are insanely useful!!

Comment: Matt, both answers are correct... I suppose I can't accept both. Your code is more compact, but zip doesn't work in Python 2.7, Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I actually couldn't exactly get what your problem is but, I tried to help you as far as I could understood...

I think you need to replace, for example 2 with 1, or 7 with 10, right? In such a case, you can create a dictionary for numbers that are to be replaced. The 'dict' below is for that purpose. It could also be done by using tuples or lists but for such purposes it is better to use dictionaries. Afterwards, just replace each element by looking into the dictionary.

The code below is a very basic one is relatively easy to understand. For sure there are more pythonic ways to do that. But if you are new into Python, the code below would be the most appropriate one.

```
import numpy as np

# Data you provided
old_num = np.array([2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 9, 8, 4, 7])
new_num = np.arange(1,10)
ELEM = np.array([ [1, 1, 3], [2, 3, 6], [3, 1, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

# Create a dict for the elements to be replaced
dict = {}
for i_num in range(len(old_num)):
    num = old_num[i_num]
    dict[num] = new_num[i_num]

# Replace the elements
for element in ELEM:
    element[1] = dict[element[1]]
    element[2] = dict[element[2]]

print ELEM
```

Comment: thanks four your help. What you've understood is correct, what you posted is what I was looking for, this is also very similar to what  Matt Adams proposes! Thanks :)